# Issues with Switch input

Tags: java, switch-statement

Okay, so I'm clearly not asking the question properly for this question. The idea is to ask a user for a number (indicating what flavor ice cream they want) associated with the flavor. Everytime I enter any number, it spits out the default. One of the issues (at least I think it is...) is the input = keyboard.nextInt();.

```
System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" What flavor of ice cream would you like? ");
    System.out.println("(1) Vanilla  (2) Peanut Butter  (3) Chocolate  (4)Chocolate Chip  (5) Mint Chocolate Chip " +
        " (6) Cookie Dough  (7) Mint Mouse tracks  (8) Coconut  (9) Pinapple  (10) Cotton Candy" +
            "(11) Mouse Tracks (12) Oreo Cookies and Cream");
    input = keyboard.nextInt();
    flavorType = input.charAt(0);

    switch(flavorType)
    {
        case 1:
            order.setFlavor ("Vanilla");
            break;
        case 2:
            order.setFlavor("Peanut-Butter");
            break;
        case 3:
            order.setFlavor ("Chocolate");
            break;
        case 4:
            order.setFlavor ("Chocolate Chip");
            break;
        case 5:
            order.setFlavor ("Mint Chocolate Chip");
            break;
        case 6:
            order.setFlavor ("Choclate Chip Cookie Dough");
            break;
        case 7:
            order.setFlavor ("Mint Mouse Tracks");
            break;
        case 8:
            order.setFlavor ("Coconut");
            break;
        case 9:
            order.setFlavor ("Pinapple");
            break;
        case 10:
            order.setFlavor ("Cotton Candy");
            break;
        case 11:
            order.setFlavor ("Mouse Tracks");
            break;
        case 12:
            order.setFlavor ("Oreo Cookies and Cream");
            break;
        default:
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(" Im sorry, that was not one of the choices, you will get two scoops " +
            " of vanilla with whipped cream,hot fudge, rainbow sprinkles, and a cherry");
            order.setFlavor ("Vanilla");
    }
```

Now, I also have the variables declared on top as such

```
        String customerName;
    double cost;
    double toppingCost = 1.25;
    int numberOfScoops;
    int numberOfDeluxe = 0;
    int numberOfToppings = 0;
    //String flavor;
    String toppingList;
    final double TAX_RATE = .08625;
    double tax;
    char choice;
    char flavorType;
    String input;
    String toppings =  " Whipped cream, syrup, and sprinkles ( Chocolate or rainbow)";
    int toppingChoice;
```

I also have in the driver program...

```
public void setFlavor (String type)
{
     flavor = type;
}
```

This is only part of the assignment. The rest of it involves scoops, toppings, etc etc. This part however is the issue, unable to get the switch statement right.

Comment: "Using constructors, I have" That's not a constructor.

Comment: "`input.charAt(0)`" Try printing out the value of this to see what is wrong. Also, see what happens if you try to enter 11.

Comment: You're reading `input` as `nextInt` and then trying to `charAt` which is a string method...

Comment: try case: '1' a char can be an integer but Im guessing that that is why you are running into problems

Comment: In fact, this code doesn't compile. `input = keyboard.nextInt();` means `input` is an `int` (or some compatible numeric type); so you can't invoke `charAt(0)` on it. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you declared:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and `order` is defined properly as well. As I wrote in the comments - you read `input` as `int` but you treat it as `String` when you try calling: `input.charAt`.

Further, you can simplify the code by using a `Map` both to figure out the choice (instead of case-switch) as well as displaying the options.

The following code will work with Java 9:

```
    Map<Integer, String> dict = new TreeMap(Map.of(1, "Vanilla",
                                                   2, "Peanut-Butter",
                                                   3, "Chocolate",
                                                   4, "Chocolate Chip",
                                                   5, "Mint Chocolate Chip",
                                                   6, "Choclate Chip Cookie Dough",
                                                   7, "Mint Mouse Tracks",
                                                   8, "Coconut",
                                                   9, "Pinapple",
                                                   10, "Cotton Candy"));

    // Map.of API allows up to 10 items - so we'll need to add the other two manually. 
    // That's also the reason that we're copying the Map.of by doing:
    // new TreeMap(Map.of(...)) - since `Map.of` returns an immutable Map which we cannot modify
    dict.put(11, "Mouse Tracks");
    dict.put(12, "Oreo Cookies and Cream");

    System.out.println("\n What flavor of ice cream would you like? ");
    dict.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(String.format("(%d) %s", k, v)));

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (null == dict.get(input)) {
        System.out.println(" Im sorry, that was not one of the choices, you will get two scoops " +
                               " of vanilla with whipped cream,hot fudge, rainbow sprinkles, and a cherry");
        order.setFlavor ("Vanilla");
    } else {
        order.setFlavor (dict.get(input));
    }
```

Comment: An integer-keyed map with contiguous keys is more easily written as a list. (Also, build the options message from the map/list, DRY).

Comment: @AndyTurner good point, had to switch to a TreeMap - but that definitely looks better - thanks!

Comment: @Frostfox why not ? Looks much better IMO

Comment: @alfasin, not in that lvl of java and not allowed to use what I don't understand

Comment: @Frostfox I'm not clear on the reasoning: same way you learned how to use switch/case statement you can learn how to use a Map. It's quite simple as you can see in the code - it maps key to value (in your case, an integer to a string) which makes it a better candidate then switch-case since there are 12 cases and you should avoid repeatedly typing all that info...